# Practicing my object literal functions using the window object

Tags: javascript, function, object, literals

I'm new to using JavaScript functions, and I made a object literal function using the window object. I'm not sure if doing a function like this is the correct way? I will post the code, and link to my codepen, so you can see the function in action. Now, to see what the various window and screen height are, you have to adjust the browser width, and refresh the page, and the width and height should adjust accordingly. Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

CODEPEN FULL PAGE VIEW:
http://codepen.io/mike316/full/eZKYRE/

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title>Template</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
          <h1>JavaScript Fun</h1>
          <span id="fun"></span>
          <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
        </div>
     </body>
   </html>
```

Code pen with html, CSS, and JavaScript.
http://codepen.io/mike316/pen/eZKYRE

My CSS:

```
body {
   background: grey;
}

.wrapper {
    background: teal;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    max-width: 60em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h1,
h2,
 p {
    text-align: center;
 }
```

My JavaScript Below:

```
var info = {
     windowHeight: "<h2>Browser Window</h2><p>width:" + window.innerWidth + "</p>",
     windowWidth: "<p>height: " + window.innerHeight + "</p>,
     screenWidth: "<h2>screen</h2><p>Width:" + window.screen.width + "</p>",
     screenHeight: "<p>height: " + window.screen.height + "</p>
     screenInfo: function() {
         return this.windowHeight + this.windowWidth + this.screenWidth + this.screenHeight;
     }
};
```

Calling my function

```
document.getElementById("fun").innerHTML = info.screenInfo();
```

Comment: You can post that as a runable snippet here.

Comment: I'm sorry RobG, I'm new to stackover flow. I'll have to research how to do that. Thank you for the information.

Comment: There are a few syntax errors, I think this is more appropriate for code review since you don't seem to have a specific issue.

Comment: I don't see any syntax errors... you can open the OPs codepen and look at the console. See? no errors!

Comment: @azium—for the code posted here, `+ "</p>` ?

Comment: good eye ;) those aren't in the codepen. my bad!

Comment: He's right azium I forgot the quotes at the end of one. Thank you Rob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fine, but I suggest an adjustment. Don't use an object here. It doesn't add anything semantically and the html properties are locked in on page load, unless you make that object again. You're better off just using functions and variables!

The following snippet does the same thing as your code except the function runs whenever you adjust the screen width, so you don't have to refresh the page to see the new values.  **[codepen](http://codepen.io/alex-wilmer/pen/pyKoZw?editors=0010)**

```
function screenInfo () {
  var windowHeight = "<h2>Browser Window</h2><p>width:" + window.innerWidth + "</p>"
  var windowWidth = "<p>height: " + window.innerHeight + "</p>"
  var screenWidth = "<h2>screen</h2><p>Width:" + window.screen.width + "</p>"
  var screenHeight = "<p>height: " + window.screen.height + "</p>"
  return windowHeight + windowWidth + screenWidth + screenHeight;
}

function addHtml () {
  document.getElementById("fun").innerHTML = screenInfo()
}

window.onresize = addHtml
addHtml()
```

Comment: Sweet. Thank you so much azium. I was wondering how to run the code without the need to refresh. That's awesome, thank you again for taking the time to help me, it really is appreciated.